# How can I add a number/text to a winform so that every copy of the application is uniquely identifiable?

Tags: .net, winforms

I want to make a simple application for Windows that displays an image containing some contact info like email and phone numbers. I install the same application on multiple computers running Windows. However, for every copy of that application, I want it to contain a unique number (invoice number, for example) right above the image as text to help me identify the individual and their purchase to better address their complaint/issue.

I am unable to decide the best way to do so. I need to change the text in the textbox for every subsequent build. I need it to be so that anyone can easily enter the unique ID without disturbing the source or causing issues with the code.

I need to add functionality so that

- There is a nested Winform at first time execution that asks me to enter the unique ID
- Once saved in the textbox, the unique ID permanently stays even if the system is restarted
- Once saved, the individual cannot change the unique ID

I'm fairly new to C# and I have just started to create simple applications integrating excel and word.

Is there any easy/better way to do this? I have been searching the internet for ideas/snippets of code with similar functionality, but could not find any.

I don't want to generate a new number here, I already have the numbers and need to enter them for every copy of the application.

Comment: So what it sounds like is that you want to display some kind of info somewhere in the app that is tied to a `purchase` of your app. You wouldn't do a build for that. Instead, you would set up and distribute `license keys` for your app, and include that reference info in the UI of the app.

Comment: This one - "Once saved, the individual cannot change the unique ID" - is going to be hard. I assume this is home computers, if so the users are effectively the admins of those computers and will, given the knowledge, have access to do whatever they want with data on it. It sounds like you want to automate a licensing scheme, can't you simply distribute license keys to your users?

Comment: @zaitsman No, the complete app is just a support page showing the email and phone numbers with the invoice number and date of purchase. The product is not the app itself, but an IoT device of sorts. But sure, I'll look into setting up license keys and including the reference info.

Comment: I mean, if you want the `unique id` you need some sort of remote system to tie that in. Then you need authentication (think login/password). Or, you can just tell the users 'bought my app? unique id here, here's your license key'. It's a bit hard to understand whya  simple app showing email and phone numbers needs some unique id

Comment: The reason you can't find any solution to your problem is because it's too vague; there are any number of contradictory ways of approaching this. You need to explain [why you want to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly is “help me identify the individual” going to do for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the user settings area to store the data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa730869(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Link answers are frowned upon, can you add some code?